# How to detect when user first starts typing text into password field, without being triggered by browser autofills/autocompletes

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked through similar questions on stack, but have not found the answer I am looking for.

I have a password field with a button that toggles visibility of the password, so the user can ensure no typoes if desired. However, I do not want this button to be used to view people's saved passwords by other people who may have access to the same computer.

So my solution was, to not enable this visibility toggle button until the user has typed something into the password field. I cannot figure out how to do this however, since any event I use to figure out when the user starts typing, is also being used by the browser when it autofills/autocompletes. I've tried the change, input, and keyup events, and each of them seems to be fired by the browser automatically as soon as the field becomes visible and it autofills a saved password. Using Chrome for testing at the moment.

html:

```
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-control needs-validation" id="sign-up-password" name="sign_up_password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary password-visibility-toggle" disabled>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
                        <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
                    </svg>
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye-slash d-none" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M13.359 11.238C15.06 9.72 16 8 16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5a7.028 7.028 0 0 0-2.79.588l.77.771A5.944 5.944 0 0 1 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755-.165.165-.337.328-.517.486l.708.709z"/>
                        <path d="M11.297 9.176a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829l.822.822zm-2.943 1.299.822.822a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829z"/>
                        <path d="M3.35 5.47c-.18.16-.353.322-.518.487A13.134 13.134 0 0 0 1.172 8l.195.288c.335.48.83 1.12 1.465 1.755C4.121 11.332 5.881 12.5 8 12.5c.716 0 1.39-.133 2.02-.36l.77.772A7.029 7.029 0 0 1 8 13.5C3 13.5 0 8 0 8s.939-1.721 2.641-3.238l.708.709zm10.296 8.884-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>
            </div>
```

javascript

```
// password visibility toggles
document.querySelectorAll( '.password-visibility-toggle' ).forEach( ( passwordVisibilityButton ) => {
    const inputGroup = passwordVisibilityButton.closest( '.input-group' );
    const passwordInput = inputGroup.querySelector( 'input' );
    passwordInput.addEventListener( 'change', ( event ) => {
        console.log( 'test' );
        if ( passwordVisibilityButton.disabled ) {
            passwordVisibilityButton.disabled = false;
            passwordVisibilityButton.addEventListener( 'click', ( event ) => {
                if ( passwordInput.getAttribute( 'type' ) == 'password' ) {
                    passwordInput.type = 'text';
                    inputGroup.querySelector( '.bi-eye' ).classList.add( 'd-none' );
                    inputGroup.querySelector( '.bi-eye-slash' ).classList.remove( 'd-none' );
                } else {
                    passwordInput.type = 'password';
                    inputGroup.querySelector( '.bi-eye' ).classList.remove( 'd-none' );
                    inputGroup.querySelector( '.bi-eye-slash' ).classList.add( 'd-none' );
                }
            } );
        }
    } );
} );
```

This code just triggers before the user inputs anything and enables the toggle button. Any ideas or advice to fix appreciated. Also using bootstrap 5.2 if that matters.

Comment: This is a virtuously-motivated endeavor, but if the user in question already has access to the password manager to fill a value, then they can unmask the field themselves in the dev tools anyway, so you're not protecting anyone by over-engineering.

Comment: @jsejcksn while true, I would at least like this to not be possible for the average laymen with a simple button click. I also read that microsoft is implementing its own feature that toggles visibility, but only works when the password is user input, so I am trying to emulate their standard.

Comment: There is no "standard" for discriminating authentic user input from synthetic (it's all layers of software all the way down from touching the keyboard / using assistive navigation tools / etc.). The best discriminator you have in JS is [`Event.isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted).

Comment: Why not just disable `autocomplete`?

Comment: @n-- because you can't when using modern browsers. they all ignore those attributes. it's been years now since that worked.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that behavior of `input` `type="password"` is totally under the browser control nowadays. Thankfully, the `input` `type="text"` is still *libre* and we can use it as we please. Thus, instead of fighting with that, we can create our own password field, albeit without password manager feature which anyway is not what we actually want on a *communal* computer. So, here it is:

```js
const toggleMap = {show: 'hide', hide: 'show'};

const group = document.querySelector( '.input-group' );
const password = group.querySelector( '#sign-up-password' );
const passmask = group.querySelector( '#sign-up-passmask' );
const toggle = group.querySelector( '.password-visibility-toggle' );

toggle.addEventListener( 'click', () => {
    group.dataset.toggle = toggleMap[group.dataset.toggle];
});

password.addEventListener( 'input', event => {
  const value = event.target.value;
  passmask.value = value.replace(/./g, '*');
  if (toggle.disabled = !value.length)
    group.dataset.toggle = 'hide';
});
```

```css
.input {
  position: relative;
}
.input > input {
  font-family: monospace;
}
#sign-up-password,
#sign-up-password::selection {
  background: transparent;
  caret-color: black;
}
#sign-up-password::selection {
  background: #F236;
}
#sign-up-passmask {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
}
.input-group[data-toggle='hide'] > .password-visibility-toggle > .bi-eye,
.input-group[data-toggle='show'] > .password-visibility-toggle > .bi-eye-slash {
  display: none;
}
.input-group[data-toggle='hide'] #sign-up-password,
.input-group[data-toggle='show'] #sign-up-passmask {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group" data-toggle="hide">
    <span class="input">
    <input type="text" class="form-control needs-validation" id="sign-up-password" name="sign_up_password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}" required>
    <input type="text" id="sign-up-passmask">
    </span>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary password-visibility-toggle" disabled>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5S0 8 0 8s3 5.5 8 5.5S16 8 16 8zM1.173 8a13.133 13.133 0 0 1 1.66-2.043C4.12 4.668 5.88 3.5 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.133 13.133 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755C11.879 11.332 10.119 12.5 8 12.5c-2.12 0-3.879-1.168-5.168-2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 1.172 8z"/>
            <path d="M8 5.5a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0 5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0-5zM4.5 8a3.5 3.5 0 1 1 7 0 3.5 3.5 0 0 1-7 0z"/>
        </svg>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-eye-slash d-none" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
            <path d="M13.359 11.238C15.06 9.72 16 8 16 8s-3-5.5-8-5.5a7.028 7.028 0 0 0-2.79.588l.77.771A5.944 5.944 0 0 1 8 3.5c2.12 0 3.879 1.168 5.168 2.457A13.134 13.134 0 0 1 14.828 8c-.058.087-.122.183-.195.288-.335.48-.83 1.12-1.465 1.755-.165.165-.337.328-.517.486l.708.709z"/>
            <path d="M11.297 9.176a3.5 3.5 0 0 0-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 1 2.829 2.829l.822.822zm-2.943 1.299.822.822a3.5 3.5 0 0 1-4.474-4.474l.823.823a2.5 2.5 0 0 0 2.829 2.829z"/>
            <path d="M3.35 5.47c-.18.16-.353.322-.518.487A13.134 13.134 0 0 0 1.172 8l.195.288c.335.48.83 1.12 1.465 1.755C4.121 11.332 5.881 12.5 8 12.5c.716 0 1.39-.133 2.02-.36l.77.772A7.029 7.029 0 0 1 8 13.5C3 13.5 0 8 0 8s.939-1.721 2.641-3.238l.708.709zm10.296 8.884-12-12 .708-.708 12 12-.708.708z"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```